# Find text between two tags

Tags: regex, scala

Below I'm attempting to use the regular expression `<hr>.find1.<hr>` to find the text between two `<hr>` tags :

```
val line = "<hr>this is find1 the line 1 <hr> tester here <hr> this is a new line <hr>"
  val toFind = "<hr>.find1.<hr>".r
  println(toFind.findFirstIn(line))
```

Output should be : `this is find1 the line 1`

But the text is not found. How to modify regular expression to find the text ?

Update : the element to be found can be in any position in List

Comment: Perhaps there's a 3rd party library that you can use rather than deal with String manipulations? Although, assuming the `hr` is an HTML tag, I'm not sure of any HTML parsing libraries in Scala off-hand.

Comment: cannot resist: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `split` on the string, like this,

```
line.trim.split("<hr>").dropWhile(_.isEmpty).take(1)
Array("this is find1 the line 1 ")
```

**Update** In order to find the partition that contains a string consider this,

```
line.split("<hr>").find( _.contains("find1"))
Some(this is find1 the line 1 )
```

Comment: thanks, please see update, the element to be found is not always first element in List

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to combine [inverse matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word) and lazy match

```
val toFind = "<hr>(((?!<hr>).)*find1.*?)<hr>".r
println(toFind.findFirstMatchIn(line).map(_.group(1)))
```